# Rexport a font loaded from @fontsource

Tags: javascript, node.js, vite

I have a component library, where I load Mantine components, customize and reexport them. I also want to customize the fonts. So In my component library I loaded to font packages from `@fontsource`:

```
import "@fontsource-variable/eczar";
import "@fontsource-variable/raleway";
```

Unfortunately this fonts don't get loaded, when another package is using the component library.

What can I do, so this fonts loaded from `@fontsource` are reexported into the packages using my component library?

I'm using vite for bundling.